# Can you explain "Did you mess with /etc/fstab before rebooting"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have struggle with AWS EC2 ubuntu server ssh connection refuse.
After I wrote mount path on /etc/fstab and reboot, I can`t access the instance.

I found your comment at [Amazon EC2 - No SSH After Reboot, Connection Refused](https://serverfault.com/questions/568240/amazon-ec2-no-ssh-after-reboot-connection-refused)

Can you help me about this.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried following the advice in [that post's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/599141/55514) about mounting your root volume as a secondary volume to another instance?  You could edit the change out of `/etc/fstab` that way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an [EBS volume backed instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630506/benefits-of-ebs-vs-instance-store-and-vice-versa) you can detach it from an instance, launch a new instance (in the same availability zone - e.g. if the broken instance is in us-west-1a, the new instance should also be in us-west-1a (not us-west-1b)) and mount it onto another healthy instance and then undo the edit /etc/fstab, or amend any errors you may have made.