# Unable to SSH into ec2 after reboot

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, yum

I hoping that this is the right place to post this. Today I was locked out of my ec2 after a reboot. This is what it says when I try to ssh:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

I've went through the following questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026148/running-ec2-instance-suddenly-refuses-ssh-connection

[Amazon EC2 - No SSH After Reboot, Connection Refused](https://serverfault.com/questions/568240/amazon-ec2-no-ssh-after-reboot-connection-refused)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P29ZHu_feU

I have already tried detaching my volume in attempt to fix sshd_config but that doesn't seem to rectify the problem. Thankfully I have an AMI before I did anything today, and I re-launched my instance and it worked fine. However, the moment I run `yum update` and rebooted my instance, I am locked out again.

These are the things that have been updated today:

```
Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                            Arch                   Version                                      Repository                                         Size
================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel                             x86_64                 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6                           rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                   32 M
Updating:
 autofs                             x86_64                 1:5.0.5-123.el6_8                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  721 k
 elasticsearch                      noarch                 2.3.5-1                                      elasticsearch-2.x                                  26 M
 httpd                              x86_64                 2.2.15-54.el6_8                              rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  833 k
 httpd-tools                        x86_64                 2.2.15-54.el6_8                              rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                   78 k
 initscripts                        x86_64                 9.03.53-1.el6_8.1                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  947 k
 java-1.7.0-openjdk                 x86_64                 1:1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el6_8                    rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                   26 M
 kernel-firmware                    noarch                 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6                           rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                   28 M
 kernel-headers                     x86_64                 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6                           rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  4.4 M
 libcgroup                          x86_64                 0.40.rc1-18.el6_8                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  130 k
 libipa_hbac                        x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  112 k
 libsss_idmap                       x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  118 k
 libtiff                            x86_64                 3.9.4-18.el6_8                               rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  345 k
 libxml2                            x86_64                 2.7.6-21.el6_8.1                             rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  805 k
 libxml2-python                     x86_64                 2.7.6-21.el6_8.1                             rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  325 k
 mdadm                              x86_64                 3.3.4-1.el6_8.5                              rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  348 k
 mod_ssl                            x86_64                 1:2.2.15-54.el6_8                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                   97 k
 nfs-utils                          x86_64                 1:1.2.3-70.el6_8.1                           rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  335 k
 nss-softokn                        x86_64                 3.14.3-23.3.el6_8                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  262 k
 nss-softokn-freebl                 x86_64                 3.14.3-23.3.el6_8                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  168 k
 perf                               x86_64                 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6                           rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  4.6 M
 php56w                             x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                          2.7 M
 php56w-cli                         x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                          2.6 M
 php56w-common                      x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                          1.2 M
 php56w-gd                          x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                          144 k
 php56w-mbstring                    x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                          944 k
 php56w-mcrypt                      x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                           25 k
 php56w-mysql                       x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                          111 k
 php56w-pdo                         x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                           94 k
 php56w-process                     x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                           35 k
 php56w-tidy                        x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                           29 k
 php56w-xml                         x86_64                 5.6.24-1.w6                                  webtatic                                          148 k
 python-libipa_hbac                 x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  107 k
 python-sssdconfig                  noarch                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  141 k
 samba4-libs                        x86_64                 4.2.10-7.el6_8                               rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  4.4 M
 sssd                               x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  108 k
 sssd-ad                            x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  211 k
 sssd-client                        x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  164 k
 sssd-common                        x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  1.1 M
 sssd-common-pac                    x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  147 k
 sssd-ipa                           x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  277 k
 sssd-krb5                          x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  143 k
 sssd-krb5-common                   x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  163 k
 sssd-ldap                          x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  209 k
 sssd-proxy                         x86_64                 1.13.3-22.el6_8.4                            rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  137 k
 tar                                x86_64                 2:1.23-15.el6_8                              rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  810 k
 tzdata                             noarch                 2016f-1.el6                                  rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  452 k
 tzdata-java                        noarch                 2016f-1.el6                                  rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  180 k
 yum                                noarch                 3.2.29-75.el6_8                              rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                  1.0 M
Removing:
 kernel                             x86_64                 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6                          @rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                 126 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade      48 Package(s)
Remove        1 Package(s)

Total download size: 144 M
```

So my question:

1. How can I make sure that ssh has started after my reboot? I am locked out of the server.
2. I highly suspect that one of the packages has errors, but I have no idea which. Any way I can pin-point?

Comment: Check logs files in detaching volume

Answer (score 1):

A `connection refused` error probably means the `sshd` service is not started and so is not listening on port 22 as it should.

Before rebooting, after updating your packages, check that *OpenSSH* is still running by typing `telnet localhost 22`. If the `telnet` package is not installed, install it using `yum install telnet`. If you see an *OpenSSH* banner, it means it is running, quit `telnet` by typing `^]` (control-]). If it is not, it means the update process went bad.
Try the following to see the state of the *sshd* service:

#### Non-systemd (pre-CentOS 7)

```
# chkconfig --list sshd
```

If you see it as `off`, enable it using the following command:

```
# chkconfig sshd on
```

And start it:

```
# service sshd start
```

Re-try `telnet`. If it is still not responding, checkout `/var/log/messages` and dig in the reason why it refused starting.

#### With systemd (CentOS 7 and up):

```
# systemctl status sshd -l
```

This command should tell you what occurred when last tried to start `sshd`. If it shows that `sshd` is not `enabled`, it means it will not start at boot time, enable it using the following:

```
# systemctl enable sshd
```

And start it if it doesn't respond:

```
# systemctl start sshd
```

Check again how did the starting process went using `systemctl status sshd`, errors happening during the process should be displayed in your console.

As for your question about debugging `yum` update process, you might want to rise `debuglevel` from 2 (default) to 10 (the higher) in `/etc/yum.conf`.